# Where to place the digital signature of the documents in my system?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

I am developing an archiving system that stores documents in a database and provides various functionalities to the user. I have added a part to sign and verify any document in the database. However, I am stuck with the logic and wondering where should I place the signing function.
Hints about my aims:

No document should be uploaded on the database without a signature

If a document is not changed it should retain its signature

If the document does not own a signature .. it should be signed with uploader's signature

The signature will not encrypt the file so it will still be readable after the signing process is applied

The initial solution I have used is to place the signing procedure in in the form that is called by the **Upload** button and store the signature of the file in a separate column in the Documents table in the database. However, that solution turned out to be invalid for my scenario as if an employee downloaded a file and then uploaded it again, then it will be signed by him and thus, the original signature will be lost. Also, the signature will be with no significance out side the system.
**My main question:**
Is there a way to store the signature inside the documents?
**Hint:** My system will deal only with PDF, JPEG, Tiff, MS Office and TXT Documents.
**Subsidiary Request:** It would be awesome if there's a way to store the signature in any type of files!

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. How would a signature be lost if a file is uploaded a second time? Are you matching a new document with an old document? If you can detect that it is the same document, then why allow it to be uploaded a second time?

Comment: No, the first idea was to place the signature in a the database with the file and lunch the signing process in the background when uploading the file. So imagine that an employee downloaded a file and then uploaded it again with no change. it will be signed by his signature and thus the original signature is now lost. i.e. if i search for all the files that has been lastly modified by a certain user, the previous scenario will return inaccurate results.

Comment: If an employee downloads a file and then uploads it again with no change, then wouldn't the original file still show up in the search for the previous user? How does it get replaced? If a file can be replaced, then leaving the original signature on it is an error, since the signer would not be approving of the changes.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed a detail, when a the same file is uploaded again, it will be uploaded as a new version of the previous file. Thus, if i want the person who worked on the last version of a certain document, i will have the user who uploaded it the last time.
I'm just thinking wondering whether there might be a way to place the signature inside the file without missing it up. which is the best solution that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to store the signature inside the documents?

A digital signature must be built using a hash of the document that is being signed. Since adding a signature to a document modifies the document (which invalidates the hash), there is no general solution to storing a digital signature inside a document.

Some document formats allow for digital signing and define what portion is to be excluded from the hash, but those formats that were listed—as far as I know—are not among them. (Though PGP could be used on TXT documents.)

Comment: I was thinking of a way to place the signature in the details of the documents. However, i'm not sure of how secure this idea is. On the other hand, the documents in my system have different details available, so i'm not sure of the validity of this idea! :S

Answer (score 0):

Since signatures sign the hash of a document, you could simply create a table mapping hashes to signatures. Thus, downloading and re-uploading a document will not remove existing signatures, since the hash will remain the same. The usefulness of this approach depends, of course, on the semantic meaning of a signature in your system.